# Regex to match specific values from from an Apache virtualhost file

Tags: php, regex

I want to match the values defined as `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` and `DocumentRoot` with regex.

Anything with a preceding `#` can be ignored.

I also would like to keep each virtualhost's definitions separate so in the example below I'd have two arrays.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  ServerAlias stage.foo.com new.foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
  ServerName bar.com
  ServerAlias store.bar.com
  #ServerAlias new.bar.com us.bar.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/bar.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My work:

`<VirtualHost(?: \*\:[0-9]*)+>\s*` will match each virtual hosting opening "tag" plus trailing white space.

`[^\#](?:ServerName|ServerAlias|DocumentRoot) ((?:(?:[\w\/\._-]+) ?)+)` will match the values I need but not as separate virtualhosts/sets/arrays.

I'm having trouble connecting them together.

Comment: In which language/tool do you need this regex?

Comment: The easiest way is to use 2 regexes, is that ok ?

Comment: @anubhava I'm guessing PHP, `preg_*` functions

Comment: @HamZa, 2 is ok. What's the reason the split up?

Comment: @allanb it will get messy if you do it with one regex. 2 regexes with some PHP will make it cleaner: first one is to match the whole virtualhost blocks, the second step is to loop through these blocks and match for `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` and `DocumentRoot`

Comment: @HamZa is quite right. I read this comment after posting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It required more code than I initially thought. Consider this code:

```
$s = <<< EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  ServerAlias stage.foo.com new.foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
  ServerName bar.com
  ServerAlias store.bar.com
  #ServerAlias new.bar.com us.bar.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/bar.com
</VirtualHost>
EOF;
$vh = array();
if (preg_match_all('~<VirtualHost ([^>]+)>(.+?)</VirtualHost>~is', $s, $arr)) {
   for($i=0; $i < count($arr[1]); $i++) {
       if (preg_match_all('/^ *(ServerName|ServerAlias|DocumentRoot) +(.+)$/im', 
                               $arr[2][$i], $m)) {
          $entries = array();
          for($j=0; $j < count($m[1]); $j++)
             $entries[$m[1][$j]] = $m[2][$j];
          $vh[$arr[1][$i]] = $entries;
       }
   }
}
print_r($vh);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [*:80] => Array
        (
            [ServerName] => foo.com
            [ServerAlias] => stage.foo.com new.foo.com
            [DocumentRoot] => /var/www/foo.com
        )

    [*:80 *:443] => Array
        (
            [ServerName] => bar.com
            [ServerAlias] => store.bar.com
            [DocumentRoot] => /var/www/bar.com
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl version:

```
$in = 0;
while ($line = <>) {
  if ($line =~ m/<VirtualHost(?: \*\:[0-9]*)+>\s*/) {
    $in = 1;
  }
  if ($line =~ m/<\/VirtualHost>/) {
    $in = 0;
  }

  if ($in eq 1) {
    if (!($line =~ m/#/) && $line =~ m/(?:ServerName|ServerAlias|DocumentRoot) ((?:(?:[-\w\/.]+) ?)+)/) {
        print $1;
        print "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, the `\w` includes the `_` => `\w: Any word character (letter, number, underscore)`... Also no need to escape the dot and the slash inside a character class...