# Pull out data between two tags

Tags: php, apache, webserver, virtualhost

I looking to pull out the informations between two tags  and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias ...
SiteName ...
...
</virtualHost>
```

it's possibile to extract the data line by line between the tags and save it in an extra file or in arrays ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569329/regex-to-match-specific-values-from-from-an-apache-virtualhost-file

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone is going to reply with a regex solution; but here's the way I would do it (because I suck at regex... for now):

```
<?php

// source
$str = '<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias ...
SiteName ...
...
</virtualHost>';

// parse
$str_parts = explode('>', $str);
$str_parts = trim(str_replace('</virtualHost', '', trim($str_parts[1])));

// debug
var_dump($str_parts);
```

Outputs:

```
string 'ServerAlias ...

SiteName ...

...' (length=34)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should match everything in between the tags you provided:

```
(?<=<VirtualHost \*\:80\>)(.|\r|\n)+(?=<\/virtualHost>)
```

Then just chomp the new lines into an array